# DnD Dice Roll Simulation

Tags: java, class, random, derived-class

I am Trying to make a simulated dice rolling game for my friends. I want to utilize two classes Dice and a child class VarDice which will let user choose how many sides. However, I am struggling to get my derived class to work properly.

This is my parent class :

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
   
   protected int numRolled;
   final Random rand = new Random();
    
    
   public void roll() {
        numRolled = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
   }
   public int getNumRolled() {
      return numRolled;
   }
   
}
```

This is the derived class:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    
    
    public class VarDice extends Dice {
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numSides;
            
            public void setNumSides(int sides) {
                numSides = sides;
            }
            
           public int getNumSides() {
              return numSides;  
            }
            
            @Override
            public void roll() {
            numRolled = rand.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
           }
    
    }
    }
```

This is finally my main code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class Main {
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
             int numSides;

             VarDice dice = new VarDice();

             numSides = scar.nextInt();

             dice.setNumSides(numSides);
             
             dice.roll();
             System.out.println("The dice come up " + dice.getNumRolled()); 
        
    
        }
    
    }
```

I want the user to be able to input how many sides are on their dice and how many dice, but my VarDice class is not overriding the roll method very well and I am a little bit lost on the errors I am getting... I appreciate the help and hope the format is appropriate.

Comment: Why do you need a `VarDice` class? How is it different from your `Dice` class? Also, the class should be called `Die` not `Dice`; "dice" is the plural of "die" and classes should be named in the singular.

Comment: Your code in `VarDice` is (for some reason) in a `main` method - why? You should put all that code directly in `VarDice`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems, here:

1. The code of `VarDice` is in a `main` method that doesn't belong here.
2. As @Bohemian pointed out in the comments, you don't really need two classes with inheritance, here. I'd drop the parent class, because the default case of 6 sides can be handled by a default constructor.
3. And yes, @Bohemian, "Dice" is the plural of "Die".

Your `Die` class could look something like this:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {
    private final Random rand;
    private int numSides;
    private int numRolled;

    public Die(int numSides) {
        this.rand = new Random();
        this.numRolled = -1;
        // custom no. of sides, 6 if invalid
        this.numSides = numSides > 0 ? numSides : 6;
    }

    public Die() {
        this(6); // 6 is default
    }

    public void setNumSides(int sides) {
        numSides = sides;
        numRolled = -1;
    }

    public int getNumSides() {
        return numSides;
    }

    public int getNumRolled() {
        if (numRolled < 0) {
            roll();
        }
        return numRolled;
    }

    public int roll() {
        numRolled = rand.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
        return numRolled;
    }
}
```

And you'd use this class something like this in your application:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // use default die
        Die die = new Die(); // create instance with default no of sides
        System.out.println(die.roll()); // roll die and print result
        System.out.println(die.getNumRolled()); // print rolled number again
        // use custom die
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Set number of sides (greater than 0): ");
        Die customDie = new Die(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(customDie.roll()); // roll custom die
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: that does not answer (explain) why the OPs code is not working

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the quick feedback and wanted to begin by saying my main method was not supposed to be there that was just from careless copy/paste lol. 2) I understand not wanting two classes, but was still wondering why my child class was not working? The purpose of VarDie is to inherit class Die traits, but then expand to take user input for a custom die.

Comment: Well, you say *"I am a little bit lost on the errors I am getting"* - what errors are you getting? If I set up your program as intended (without the extraneous `main` in `VarDice`), it seems to work just fine. I input `20` and I get `The dice come up 16`. What is it that's not working?

Comment: I apologize!! I believe it is the site that I am using then that is giving me these mysterious errors then. I will try to use another resource to edit my code in and move from there. Again I appreciate the feedback, and for the second approach to not having two classes :). I will be sure to update my progress as well since I am positive I will have more questions later on with saving each roll and printing out results lol.

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes I noticed:

the line `numSides = scar.nextInt();` should be `numSides = scnr.nextInt();`

the class VarDice has wrapped everything in `public static void main(String[] args) {...}`. Remove this wrapping to ensure that the code is a part of the class and not the method.

With those changes, the code worked for me.